# How can my web app know if the user is logged?

Tags: php, laravel

i have created a simple log in app in laravel, it works fine but whenever i click "go back" it seems to return to the log in page. how can my application know if the user is logged in an jump to safe page whenever i click "go back"? basic stuff i know but I'm new to laravel. help?

Comment: You can start by showing your code, and also reading up about sessions.

Comment: Modern browsers usually just take a page from their cache when you press "Back". You cannot affect on that.

Comment: By using a conditional statement if/else

Answer (score 1):

**Determining If A User Is Authenticated**

To determine if the user is already logged into your application, you may use the check method:

```
if (Auth::check())
{
    // The user is logged in...
}
```

Note that you should ensure that the "previous" page is not being cached by the browser, otherwise it'll just display the cached page without asking the server. Set appropriate no-cache headers to do so. Don't do this for all your pages, since you do want to cache some pages.

You better read Laravel Manual. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security

Comment: @Shark Note that you should ensure that the "previous" page is not being cached by the browser, otherwise it'll just display the cached page without asking the server. Set appropriate no-cache headers to do so. Don't do this for *all* your pages, since you *do* want to cache *some* pages.

Comment: Nice explanation, I added into answer @deceze

Comment: @Shark : Thick as answer if this is answer your question.